# I want to optimize a stored procedure that uses IN clause and a regex_str function. I am not sure that how I should optimize it more?

Tags: regex, performance, oracle, plsql, query-optimization

The response time I am getting is around 200ms.
I want to optimize it more.
How can I achieve this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE GETSTORES
(
LISTOFOFFERIDS IN VARCHAR2,
REF_OFFERS OUT TYPES.OFFER_RECORD_CURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN REF_OFFERS FOR
  SELECT
  /*+ PARALLEL(STORES 5) PARALLEL(MERCHANTOFFERS 5)*/
  MOFF.OFFERID,
  s.STOREID,
  S.LAT,
  s.LNG
  FROM
  MERCHANTOFFERS MOFF
  INNER JOIN STORES s ON MOFF.STOREID =S.STOREID
  WHERE
  MOFF.OFFERID IN
  (
    SELECT
      REGEXP_SUBSTR(LISTOFOFFERIDS,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
    FROM
      DUAL CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(LISTOFOFFERIDS, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
  )
  ;
END
GETSTORES;
```

I am using the regex_substr to get a list of OfferIDs from the comma separated string that comes in LISTOFOFFERIDS.
I have created the index on STOREID of the Stores table but to no avail.
A new approach to achieve the same is also fine if its faster.

The types declaration for the same:

```
create or replace

    PACKAGE TYPES
    AS
    TYPE OFFER_RECORD
    IS
      RECORD(
      OFFER_ID MERCHANTOFFERS.OFFERID%TYPE,
      STORE_ID STORES.STOREID%TYPE,
      LAT STORES.LAT%TYPE,
      LNG STORES.LNG%TYPE
      );
    TYPE OFFER_RECORD_CURSOR
    IS
      REF
      CURSOR
        RETURN OFFER_RECORD;
      END
      TYPES;
```

The plan for the select reveals following information:

```
Plan hash value: 1501040938

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                  | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                           |                |   276 | 67620 |    17  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                                 |                |   276 | 67620 |    17  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                             |                |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                            |                |   276 | 61272 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     VIEW                                   | VW_NSO_1       |     1 |   202 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      HASH UNIQUE                           |                |     1 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING (UNIQUE)|                |       |       |            |          |
|   7 |        FAST DUAL                           |                |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                       | OFFERID_INDEX  |   276 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID             | MERCHANTOFFERS |   276 |  5520 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL                        | STORES         |  9947 |   223K|    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("MERCHANTOFFERS"."STOREID"="STORES"."STOREID")
   6 - filter( REGEXP_SUBSTR ('M1-Off2,M2-Off5,M2-Off9,M5-Off4,M10-Off1,M1-Off3,M2-Off4,M3-Off2,M4-Of
              f6,M5-Off1,M6-Off1,M8-Off1,M7-Off3,M1-Off1,M2-Off1,M3-Off1,M3-Off4,M3-Off5,M3-Off6,M4-Off1,M4-Off7,M2
              -Off2,M3-Off3,M5-Off2,M7-Off1,M7-Off2,M1-Off7,M2-Off3,M3-Off7,M5-Off5,M4-Off2,M4-Off3,M4-Off5,M8-Off2
              ,M6-Off2,M1-Off5,M1-Off6,M1-Off9,M1-Off8,M2-Off6,M2-Off7,M4-Off4,M9-Off1,M6-Off4,M1-Off4,M1-Off10,M2-
              Off8,M3-Off8,M6-Off3,M5-Off3','[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
   8 - access("MERCHANTOFFERS"."OFFERID"="$kkqu_col_1")
```

Comment: can you post the explain plan of the select?

Comment: Plan of select as in? Do you want the types declaration? I have edited the post to include that.

Comment: The Oracle explain plan. [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm)

Comment: I have edited the post and included the plan. Thanks :)

Comment: ok. Appears you need an index on stores(STOREID)

Comment: Ya i have the index in place. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How many distinct stores do you get by a common query and how many stores are in table STORES? I guess it shoud choose the index way. The tables are analysed. With dbms_stats.gather_table_stats?

Comment: The stores are totally distinct. As in the STOREID is the primary key.

Comment: You didn't respond to my question. I repeat the question: For the example presented, how many distinct stores you get (`select count(distinct storeid) from (your_query)`) and how many stores are in the STORES table? (`Select count(*) from Stores`)?  Question2: Have you tried the compound index suggested by APC?

Comment: Oh i didnt get the question then. The distinct query returns 9946 and the total number is also 9946. The query returns 13970 records which is join of offers and stores. Total count of offers is 13971. Ya about the compound index, I have individual index on all these fields, should i compbine them?

Answer (score 1):

1. If your server supports it (seems you want it), change the hints into `/*+ PARALLEL(S 8) PARALLEL(MOFF 8)*/`. When you have aliases you must use the aliases in the hints.
2. you should try the compound index suggested by APC(`STORES(STOREID, LAT, LNG)`)
3. Please respond to the questions: For the example presented, how many distinct stores you get (`select count(distinct storeid) from (your_query)`) and how many stores are in the STORES table? (`Select count(*) from Stores`)?
4. Have you analysed the table with `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats`?
5. I believe the `connect by` query is NOT the problem. It runs in 0.02 seconds.

Comment: Oh i didnt get the question then. The distinct query returns 9946 and the total number is also 9946. The query returns 13970 records which is join of offers and stores. Total count of offers is 13971. Ya about the compound index, I have individual index on all these fields, should i compbine them? After analyzing how to see the gathered stats?

Comment: 9946? ouch. What returns `select count(*) from MERCHANTOFFERS`? I think all you can do is to put the parallel hint ( `/*+ PARALLEL(S 8) */`).

Comment: Seems the compound index would not be too useful. You need to read the entire table `STORES`. The table Stores contain long columns as Descriptions, etc?

Comment: No the stores only has three feilds ID and Lat and Lng

Comment: What returns select count(*) from MERCHANTOFFERS? I think all you can do is to put the parallel hint ( /*+ PARALLEL(S 8) */).

Comment: It returns 13971. When I put the hint, do I need to do anything else on the DB level to take advantage of it?

Comment: So, you're querying for all records... Just add full(MOFF) and parallel(MOFF 8). Your query will fly. `Select /*+ PARALLEL(S 8) PARALLEL(MOFF 8) FULL(MOFF) FULL(S)*/` on the same line. This will speed THIS query. If you ask for an offer that is in a single store, the first version will be faster. And... the hint should just work. you can verify if works consulting the explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at you explain plan the timings for each step are the same: there is no obvious candidate to focus on tuning.

The sample you posted has fifty tokens for OFFERID.  Is that representative?  They map to 276 STORES - is that a representative ratio?  Do any offers hit more than one Store?

276 rows is about 2.7% of the rows which is a small-ish sliver: however, as STORES seems to be a very compact table it's marginal as to whether indexed reads would be faster than a full table scan.

The only obvious thing you could do to squeeze more juice out of the database would be to build a compound index on STORES(STOREID, LAT, LNG); presumably it's not a table which sees much DML so the overhead of an additional index wouldn't be much.

One last point: your query executes in 0.2s.  So how much faster do you want it to go?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! I want to bring it to around 0.1ms. Any other approach that you can suggest?? As in using functions instead of Stored proc .. or anything... kinda desperate here :(

Comment: A function is a stored procedure which returns a value.  It will not have a different performance profile.

Comment: "kinda desperate here" But not desperate enough to answer my questions on data volumes or skew.  Also, have you tried the compound index I suggested?

Comment: Sorry was in a meeting. Yes offers can hit more than one store. The 50 tokens is not representative its just a random number. At runtime we can have offers from 1 to 1000. Is there anyother way to achieve the IN query in a more optimized way?

Answer (score 0):

Consider dropping the regex on the join, so the join can happen fast.
If there are indexes on the join columns, chances are the join may move from nested loops
to a hashed join of some sort.

Once you have that result set (with hopefully fewer rows), then filter it with your regex.

You may find that the WITH statement helpful in this scenerio.

Something on the order of this.  ( untested example )

```
WITH
base AS
(
    SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(STORES 5) PARALLEL(MERCHANTOFFERS 5) */
           moff.OFFERID,
              s.STOREID,
              s.LAT,
              s.LNG
    FROM MERCHANTOFFERS moff
    INNER JOIN STORES s 
    ON MOFF.STOREID = S.STOREID
),
offers AS
(
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(LISTOFOFFERIDS,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) offerid
    FROM DUAL 
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(LISTOFOFFERIDS, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT base.*
FROM base,
     offers
WHERE base.offerid = offers.offerid
```

Oracle may execute the two views into in memory tables, then join.

No guarentees. Your milage may vary.  You were looking for ideas.  This is an idea.
The very best of luck to you.

If I recall a hints chapter correctly, when you alias your table names, you need to use that alias in your hint.  /*+ PARALLEL(s 5) PARALLEL(moff 5) */

I would be curious as to why you decided on the value 5 for your hints.  I was under the impression that Oracle would chose a best value for it, depending on system load and other mysterious conditions.

Comment: Temporary tables write to disk. So this approach is extremely unlikely to offer a 0.1s improvement in performance.

Comment: depends on the size of the table.

Comment: Hi EvilTech .. Can you show how I can apply the regex later? The regex actually separates the comma separated list for acceptable in the IN clause... Any other better way to do it?

Comment: I believe the `connect by` query is NOT the problem. It runs in 0.02 seconds.

Comment: Hmmm .. But any alternative to IN clause?